# How to call a backing bean method without using h:commandButton or h:commandLink

Tags: forms, jsf

I have a JSF form with only one input and no submit button. The form is submitted when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I would like to trigger a backing bean method on submit of that form. How can I achieve this?

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.propertyName}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you mean to invoke a "Java method" or a "JavaScript function"? You keep saying "function" and you have `[javascript]` tagged, but your title contains "backing bean" too.

Comment: @BalusC , a backing bean function/java method, and am tagging javascript for the possibility of using mojarra.jsfcljs

Comment: "Function" has an different meaning in Java. Never mix them with methods. You actually want to say "backing bean method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you are trying to achieve could be done without a submit type input component in the form. If you just don't like a button to be displayed you can hide it in the resulting xhtml page with `style="display: none"`. The form still will be submitted when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed and you will get a desired behavior.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.propertyName}"/>
    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{searchBean.method()}" style="display: none"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: thanks alex, I actually didn't find a direct solution, so I solved it like you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a handler to the `submit` event of the form.  If you give your form an ID (eg: "myForm"):

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: These are bad practices. Events should be abstracted from the form, not inline. It promotes readability and nicer code

Comment: @SterlingArcher of course, I was just illustrating putting the `submit` handler on the `form` itself, in contrast with a `click` handler on a `button`.  No doubt the OP will do it properly

Answer (score 0):

You came submit with ajax call-

```
<h:form>
<div class="search">

    <span class="searchIcon icon-magnifier"></span>
    <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.propertyName}" id="propertyName"
        a:placeholder="" readonly="false"></h:inputText>
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="{searchBean.beanMethod}"/>
</div>
```